# Can I use an Android vector graphic with ArcGIS MapView graphicsOverlay.graphics?

Tags: android, kotlin, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I'm working with an Android ESRI ArcGIS map application. I want to use an android vector graphic resource on the ArcGIS mapView. I'm able to use a png resource. How do I use a vector graphic IE: flag.xml resource.
I'm using the ArcGIS Kotlin SDK 200.2.0.

Here is how I create a graphic for a png image.

```
// using a bitmap .png image
val first = routeStops[0]
val startPin = PictureMarkerSymbol.createWithImage(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_source) as BitmapDrawable)
val startGraphic = Graphic(first.geometry, startPin)
graphicsOverlay.graphics.add(startGraphic)
```

Not sure what to try? I tried getDrawable() and cast to a VetorDrawable but that did not work.